# How am I getting the right result even if object x is not defined in R for the below code

Tags: r

Can anyone please explain me, how am I getting the right result in R, even if the argument 'x' is not defined here:

```
    cars<-c("Honda","Toyota","Tata","Maruti","Skoda")
car.names<-function(x){
for(name in x){
if(name=="Tata")
break
print(name)
}
}
car.names(cars)
```

Result: "Honda", "Toyota"

Comment: I do not understand what your question is...

Answer (score 0):

The variable x in the function is mapped to what is input in the function call, in this case cars. This means that x in the for loop is already defined as the contents of the variable cars. I think the function works because x is a vector, so the for loop runs in the positions along the vector. If you changed x to y the function should stop working as y is undefined.

Answer (score 0):

Regardless of how you call the function, for example:

```
car.names(cars)

car.names(c("Toyota","Tata","Maruti"))
```

The first argument will always be known as `x` inside the function, because that's how it's defined in this line:

```
car.names <- function(x) {
}
```